# javascript how to omit a param from an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object as follows:

```
   test: {a:"value1",b:"value2",...},
```

I want to omit certain params and get the remaining in a new array

```
eg: get {a:"value1",... } i want to omit b:"value1"
```

how to do this in javascript in one liner or more.

Comment: Lodash _.pick will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To set "a" as undefined**

```
let test = {a: "v1", b: "v2"};
test.a = undefined;
console.log(test); // {a: undefined, b: "v2"}
```

**To remove "a" completely**

```
let test = {a: "v1", b: "v2"};
delete test.a;
console.log(test); // {b: "v2"}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**rest properties**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/object-rest-spread).

```js
const test = { a: "value1", b: "value2", c: "value3"};
const { b, ...obj } = test;

console.log(obj);
```

**One Note** - This requires the most modern version of Javascript... )

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi Check your JS version of your environment. `rest` properties are in the proposal, but have already been implemented in modern browsers

Comment: i am using this code in a reactjs applicaiton. I am using reactjs by including it in the html file via script tag. so how to include rest properties advanced javascript

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi I have updated the comment above. If your browser is modern you can use it. For production you anyway need to transpile your code.

Comment: Minor notice: that's "object destructuring", not "rest properties"

Comment: @georg Of course. After that I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce` with `Object.keys` to create a new object with the specified keys removed:

```js
const obj = {
  a: "foo",
  b: "bar",
  c: 9001,
  d: true,
}

function omit(obj, keys) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((newobj, key) => {
    if (!keys.includes(key)) newobj[key] = obj[key];
    return newobj;
  }, {});
}

console.log(omit(obj, ["b", "d"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const _ = require ('lodash');
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };

var result = _.pick(object, ['a', 'c']);
```

Or ( thanks @Crice):

```
var result = _.omit (object, ['b']);
```

Comment: Note that lodash also has a `_.omit` method if you'd rather specify the keys to leave out rather than those to keep.